# std::thread --- no matching constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

So, I have this bit of code, which is supposed to be run as a separate thread:

```
template<class Iterator>
void thread_launcher(Iterator start, Iterator fin, size_t sort_type) {
    // Blah blah
    mixed_sort<less<int>>(start, fin, sort_type);
    // blah blah
}
```

And this code is supposed to create this thread:

```
for (size_t sort_type = 2; sort_type!= 7; ++sort_type) {
    // blah
    t[sort_type] = thread(thread_launcher, copy.begin(), copy.end(), sort_type);
}
```

, where `t` is an array of `thread`.

The problem is --- when I try to compile this, I get this error:

```
main.cpp:245:32: error: no matching constructor for initialization of
      'std::__1::thread'
  ...= thread(thread_launcher, copy.begin(), copy.end(), sort_type);
       ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:349:9: note: 
      candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Fp'
thread::thread(_Fp&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
```

I don't understand what did I do wrong, though it's the first time I've ever worked with multithreading, let alone `std::thread`. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you try passing `thread_launcher<decltype(copy.begin())>` instead of `thread_launcher`?

Comment: You could also use a lambda, [sample here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35173048/3747990)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure without all the details, but it is striking that you're passing `thread_launcher` as an argument. This is not a function, but rather a *function template*.

Consider the following:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T)
{

}


int main()
{
    thread t(foo<int>, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

By me, this builds, but when I change it to

```
thread t(foo, 3);
```

it fails to build.

By you, then, you might want to change things to

```
thread(
     thread_launcher<decltype(begin(copy))>, 
     begin(copy),
     end(copy), 
     sort_type)
```

Comment: But shouldn't it have inferred the missing template arguments by itself? Because, for example, the `mixed_sort` function also has the same `class Iterator` template argument, but it compiles just fine

Comment: The problem is that, *before that*, you're passing it something that is just not a function pointer. It's a "factory" of functions (and function pointers). It just doesn't reach the stage to which you're referring.

Comment: Ahh, okay. I think I got it, thanks